# Half-fluid design with ZURB Foundation?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I am a pretty newbie with Foundation, but is there a possibility to make the default grid width bigger, or better, just 80% of the screen width with an additional min-width?

If it is not possible with Foundation, is it possible with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the good things about Foundation 3 is that it is built with [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), so the CSS for the grid system relies completely on variables.

The width of the row is styled in [`scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/06a8f20433420c231f6a294ee1999e87ff8c69c3/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss):

```
/* The Grid ---------------------- */

.row { width: $rowWidth; max-width: 100%; min-width: $screenSmall; margin: 0 auto;
  .row { width: auto; max-width: none; min-width: 0; margin: 0 (-($columnGutter/2)); }

  &.collapse {
    .column, .columns { padding: 0; }
  }
  .row { width: auto; max-width: none; min-width: 0; margin: 0 (-($columnGutter/2));
    &.collapse { margin: 0; }
  }
}
```

The total width of the row relies on the `$rowWidth` variable, that in its turn is defined in [`scss/foundation/_settings.scss`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/06a8f20433420c231f6a294ee1999e87ff8c69c3/scss/foundation/_settings.scss):

```
// Grid Settings

$rowWidth: 1000px !default;
$columnGutter: 30px !default;
$totalColumns: 12 !default;
$mobileTotalColumns: 4 !default;
$blockGridElements: 12 !default; // Highest number of block grid elements, Maximum of 24 supported
```

So **you need to change the `$rowWidth` variable to whatever size you need**.

Comment: setting it to 80% worked for the grid, but not for the top-nav

Comment: @Stasik try "adding `.contain-to-grid` to top-bar to make it full width but content on grid."

Comment: this is a bit broken, however it can be fixed manually by setting .contain-to-grid width not to $rowWidth (which is e.g. 80%), but by 100% ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using Foundation 4 I've simply added

```
.row { max-width: 100%; }
```

to the styles. Works for `rows` as well as `top-bar`

Comment: But does in enlarge the components/sections inside the row? B'coz when I did this, the divs appeared little bigger to me. I could spot this, because all divs in my code had an image inside it, and the image appeared bigger than its normal size.

Comment: It does as all columns are just %, so they scale.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SASS and version 5 of foundation you can customize rows with:

```
$row-width: 100%;
```